# 12v DC Voltage Drop under load

Tags: pcb, 12v

I have a Autopilot PCB which runs a 12v dc hydraulic pump which has been running fine until now. When the pump is not attached the output from the PCB is 12v. When i connect the pump the output drops to 4v and the pump doesn't run. Ive tested the pump and it is working fine.

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/1zciiw3/8]

Ive tested the large capacitor and it seems fine. If someone could point me in the right direction as to where I should be looking I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Only managed to find this diagram. I will keep looking.

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/ra7p77.jpg]

Pump specs

[image]

The power supply is a large battery bank which is fed by a 75hp diesel engine.

Comment: If you would supply us with some more info (meaning specifications) concerning the power supply and the pump then maybe we can make a useful comment. With this limited info it's anyone's guess.

Comment: If you send a crappy picture of a skin sore to your doctor do you believe a correct diagnosis would happen?

Comment: As others have said, more info is needed. Do you have a schematic of the Autopilot PCB? A wild guess with the current info is it may be a faulty NTC (used for in rush current limiting)

Comment: Apologies. Im trying to find the info now.

Comment: Fuse, relay, MOSFET (in that order). If the fuse was bypassed at any point or the board fiddled with, maybe blown off trace(s).

Comment: Thanks. Fuse is good. Ill check the relay then the MOSFET.

Comment: When checking the fuse, be aware that it can read low resistance on a multi-meter and still have a high resistance under load.

Comment: I tested the IRF9521 MOSFET and I'm getting .5v in diode mode across the drain and source in "off" mode. And 13Mohms across the drain and source in "off" mode. Does this sound right?  http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25885/SUTEX/IRF9521.html

Comment: What is the output pcb current when you attach the pump?

Comment: The pump doesnt run so Im guessing its drawing no amps. I cant check it at the moment.

Comment: Tested the relay. It is perfect. Ordered a replacement MOSFET as I cant be sure im testing it properly.

Comment: Replaced the MOSFET. The old one was perfect. Any other suggestions? What could cause the PCB to not be supplying enough amps?

Comment: Check the current path from battery +Ve through to pump, then back to the battery -Ve. It's a crappy job (more so without a schematic) but *somewhere* you *will* find that ~8V drop. Check the voltage across the MOSFET first - it should be near zero. If it isn't, it hasn't turned on fully - now you start checking whatever it is that drives the Gate.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your pump need more current.  give it from SMPS or transformer (15 -20 A)

if the current supplied is not enough for the pump it will drop the voltage

check your pump current rating and give required current,

pump draws more current when load is applied